# Should I use a global "currentUserId" var in my Meteor publish code?

Tags: meteor, global-variables, publish-subscribe

In my \server\publications.js file, I've got code like this:

```
Meteor.publish("jobLocations", function () {
  var currentUserId = this.userId;
  return JobLocations.find({createdBy: currentUserId});
});

Meteor.publish("workers", function () {
  var currentUserId = this.userId;
  return Workers.find({createdBy: currentUserId});
});

. . .
```

IOW, I'm using a local var named "currentUserId" in each publish method.

Would it be preferable to change it to this:

```
var currentUserId = null;
Meteor.publish("jobLocations", function () {
  currentUserId = this.userId;
  return JobLocations.find({createdBy: currentUserId});
});

Meteor.publish("workers", function () {
  currentUserId = this.userId;
  return Workers.find({createdBy: currentUserId});
});
```

...or is there some reason why each publish method needs its own local "currentUserId" var?

Comment: You don't need to use a var, you can just use `this.userId` where you need it..

Comment: Good point; I was just using the sample code from "Your First Meteor App" without looking at it with much of a critical eye.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to JavaScript functions running to completion there would be no issue in using a global as long as there is no callback and it is a primitive value (not an object as you may have issues with pass-by-sharing and asynchronous functions altering this object).

In your case it is irrelevant as challett pointed: You use the `var` immediately so no need to declare it in the first place.